# How to pass list of tuples through a object method in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, object, iterator, instance

Having this frustrating issue where i want to pass through the tuples in the following list
through a method on another list of instances of a class that i have created

```
list_1=[(0, 20), (10, 1), (0, 1), (0, 10), (5, 5), (10, 50)]
instances=[instance[0], instance[1],...instance[n]]
```

```
results=[]
pos_list=[]
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    a,b=List_1[i]
    result=sum(instance.method(a,b) for instance in instances)
    results.append(result)
    if result>=0:
        pos_list.append((a,b))
print(results)
print(pos_list)
```

the issue is that all instances are taking the *same* tuple, where as i want the method on the first instance to take the first tuple and so on.
I ultimately want to see it append to the new list (pos_list) if the sum is >0.

Anyone know how i can iterate this properly?

---

EDIT
It will make it clearer if I print the result of the sum also.

Basically I want the sum to perform as follows:

```
result = instance[0].method(0,20), instance[1].method(10,1), instance[2].method(0,1), instance[3].method(0,10), instance[4].method(5,5), instance[5].method(10,50)
```

For info the method is just the +/- product of the two values depending on the attributes of the instance.
So results for above would be:

```
result = [0*20 - 10*1 - 0*1 + 0*10 - 5*5 + 10*50] = [465]
pos_list=[(0, 20), (10, 1), (0, 1), (0, 10), (5, 5), (10, 50)]
```

except what is actually doing is using the same tuple for all instances like this:

```
result = instance[0].method(0,20), instance[1].method(0,20), instance[2].method(0,20), instance[3].method(0,20), instance[4].method(0,20), instance[5].method(0,20)
result = [0*20 - 0*20 - 0*20 + 0*20 - 0*20 + 0*20] = [0]
pos_list=[]
```

and so on for (10,1) etc.

How do I make it work like the first example?

Comment: Hi! Can you be more explicit about the sum? Do you want to sum the result of  `method` of the first instance on the first element of the tuple to the result of  `method` of the second instance on the second element of the tuple, and so on? And repeat it for each item of `list_1`, considering again the whole list `l1`?

Comment: hi, yes that's correct! My problem is that is using the one tuple for all instances for every loop, am trying to think on how to make it go one by one (i.e. first instance to first tuple and so on)

Comment: But you will end up having the same result of the sum for each iteration in this way, so appending all the elements to `pos_list` or none.

Comment: any idea what i could do it differently to get it what i want it to do?

Comment: You should explain more in detail what do you have in mind, adding an example of your input and expected output

Comment: updated my question section, hope that now makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many thanks for the above! I have it working now.
Wasn't able to use args given my method had a bit more to it but the use of zip is what made it click

```
import random
rand=random.choices(list_1, k=len(instances))

results=[]
pos_list=[]
for r in rand:
    x,y=r
result=sum(instance.method(x,y) for instance,(x,y) in zip(instances, rand))
results.append(result)
if result>=0:
    pos_list.append(rand)
print(results)
print(pos_list)
```

for list of e.g.

```
rand=[(20, 5), (0, 2), (0, 100), (2, 50), (5, 10), (50, 100)]
```

this returns the following

```
results=[147]
pos_list=[(20, 5), (0, 2), (0, 100), (2, 50), (5, 10), (50, 100)]
```

so exactly what I wanted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can compute your sum using `zip` to generate all the pairs of correspondent instances and tuples.

```py
result=sum(instance.payout(*t) for instance, t in zip(instances, List_1))
```

The `zip` will stop as soon as it reaches the end of the shortest of the two iterators. So if you have 10 instances and 100 tuples, `zip` will produce only 10 pairs, using the first 10 elements of both lists.

The problem I see in your code is that you are computing this sum for each element of `List_1`, so if `payout` produces always the same result with the same inputs (e.g., it has no memory or randomness), the value of `result` will be the same at each iteration. So, in the end, `results` will be composed by the same value repeated a number of times equal to the length of `List_1`, while `pos_list` will contain all (the sum is greater than 0) or none (the sum is less or equal to zero) of the input tuples.

Instead, it would make sense if items of `List_1` were lists or tuples themselves:

```py
List_1 = [
    [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)],
    [(6, 7), (8, 9), (10, 11)],
    [(12, 13), (14, 15), (16, 17)],
]
```

So, in this case, supposing that your class for `instances` is something like this:

```py
class Goofy:
    def __init__(self, positive_sum=True):
        self.positive_sum = positive_sum

    def payout(self, *args):
        if self.positive_sum:
            return sum(args)
        else:
            return -1 * sum(args)

instances = [Goofy(i) for i in [True, True, False]]
```

you can rewrite your code in this way:

```py
results=[]
pos_list=[]
for el in List_1:
    result = sum(g.payout(*t) for g, t in zip(instances, el))
    results.append(result)
    if result >= 0:
        pos_list.append(el)
```

Running the previous code, `results` will be:

```sh
[-3, 9, 21]
```

while `pop_list`:

```sh
[[(6, 7), (8, 9), (10, 11)], [(12, 13), (14, 15), (16, 17)]]
```

If you are interested only in `pop_list`, you can compact your code in only one line:

```py
pop_list = list(filter(lambda el: sum(g.payout(*t) for g, t in zip(instances, el)) > 0, List_1))
```